# Furnace Ignitor Ticking Continuously

Tags: furnace

My furnace is a Carrier 58GS075. It seems to cycle correctly:

1. Igniter sparks and ignites*
2. 20-30 second pause.
3. Main burners are opened and ignite.
4. 30-60 seconds and blower turns on.
5. Remains on until heat is satisfied.
6. Main burners shutoff.
7. Blower turns off 45 seconds later.

However, during the whole process (steps 1-5) the igniter is rapidly sparking, but the flame is already established after 1-2 sparks.

I bought a whole new igniter off eBay a few months ago to try to fix this issue, however it is still occurring.

I also bought a whole new circuit board about 2 months ago for a different issue. The igniter issue persisted between circuit boards.

I would imagine the cycle would be irregular if the furnace did not think the igniter was lit? (shutting down main burners, etc) But it cycles correctly so maybe it is something else?

**Edit: Added videos**
Initial igniter sparking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbkZZnSz4-Q
Sparking during main burners: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGxUm6lNw-w

Comment: It sounds like the thermocouple (the sensor that detects the pilot) is bad but that would usually shut the gas off.

Comment: This is a common problem with the three wire pilot assembly in this (and other) unit(s). However, the problem is typically solved by installing a new pilot assembly.  You mention that you purchase a replacement on ebay, are you sure the unit you purchased was new?  What does the pilot flame look like (a photo or video might be useful)? Have you made sure the wires are firmly connected to the spark module?

Comment: @EdBeal This unit doesn't have a separate thermocouple.  The pilot assembly is made up of the pilot orifice, the spark electrode, and a bimetal  switch.

Comment: Thanks tester101 I did not look that model up + that should be an answer.

Comment: I will get a picture. No I am not 100% sure the eBay pilot assembly was new.

Comment: Yes I have checked the wires, but will check again.

Comment: @Tester101 I added videos.

Comment: Is the pilot orifice dirty?  Notice how the pilot flame becomes erratic when the burner ignites, that shouldn't happen. You might want to have an HVAC company come out and take a look.

Comment: @Tester101 I bought another pilot assembly from Amazon. It had a new orifice. Same issue persisted. If it is not the pilot assembly, what is telling the igniter to keep sparking?

Comment: @rys maybe a short in the ignition module?  Is the pilot flame more stable with the new pilot assembly?

Comment: No seemed similar.

Comment: Sure I can try that next.

Comment: Would a short be in the spark electrode wire? Or the module itself? Should I replace both?